# Ansible get_url is timing out

Tags: ansible, centos

I have troubles downloading a jar file from Artifactory on a CentOs7 instance with Ansible. It is the first time i do that on a Linux instance.

I am using the win_get_url module on every Windows instance and it is working normaly

```
   - name: download artifacts
     win_get_url:
       url: '{{ some_url }}'
       username: '{{ jfrog_username }}'
       password: '{{ jfrog_password }}'
       dest: '{{ some_dest }}'
       force: no
       proxy_url: {{ some_proxy }}
```

When i use the get_url module it is timeing out. I have noticed that the Linux module doen't support the parameter "proxy_url". so i have tried to run the tasks with some other parameters like

```
   - name: download artifacts
     get_url:
       url: '{{ some_url }}'
       username: '{{ jfrog_username }}'
       password: '{{ jfrog_password }}'
       dest: '{{ some_dest }}'
       force: no
       use_proxy: yes
       http_agent"{{ proxy }}
       checksum: {{ checksum }}
```

But it gives me always this error:

```
  "status": -1,
  "url": "https://some_url/installer.jar",
  "msg": "Failed to connect to www.jfrog.io at port 443: [Errno 110] Connection timed out",
  "invocation": {
```

I have checked the Firewall setting and https is open from/into this server.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

If i use curl, based on the tip mentioned by Zeitounator it works! i can download the file with:

```
     curl -O -u --user user:password 'https://some_url/installer.jar'
```

I am not using proxy password. When curl asked voor proxy password i just pressed enter and curl downloaded the file without any issues.

But with Ansible still no luck.

Comment: What happens when you `curl https://some_url/installer.jar` directly on a command line on the server ?

Comment: @Zeitounator please see the update.

Comment: You are mentioning proxy in your latest update. Did you configure the proxy in ansible ? (i.e. send it in `environment` as a task option or directly in the play)

Comment: @Zeitounator no i didn't do that. I will go figure out how. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following our comments: you need to declare the proxy your are using in an [`environment`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_environment.html) stanza, either at task or play level.

```
environment:
  http_proxy: http://my_proxy:8080
  https_proxy: http://my_proxy:8080
  no_proxy: 127.0.0.1,localhost,.my_local_domain.com
```

If your proxy needs authentification, you'll have to pass the auth in the uri:

```
http://user:password@my_proxy:8080
```

Answer (score 6):

if proxy is configured @Zeitounator answered it correctly.

But still can try adding below:

```
- name: download artifacts
 get_url:
   url: '{{ some_url }}'
   username: '{{ jfrog_username }}'
   password: '{{ jfrog_password }}'
   dest: '{{ some_dest }}'
   force: no
   use_proxy: yes
   http_agent"{{ proxy }}
   checksum: {{ checksum }}
   timeout: 30
```

As default timeout for get_url module is 10 seconds